# ffmpeg encoding & decoding webcam stream into h264 file using Intel Quick Sync Video hw accelerated decoding

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, encode, intel-media-sdk

Using ubuntu 18.04 on NUC. I'm succeeding to use it from a file input. How can I get my webcam input to work with the HW accelerated.

Succeeded running the following:
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mp4 -vf hwdownload,format=nv12 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.yuv

Comment: Have you got it solved? I want to use QSV on /dev/video0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use v4l2?

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0
```

framerate and resolution can be taken by command:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```